# MobilePush Delay Registration Function

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

We wanted to register the contact and device using the custom contact key that we have currently in place to Mobile Push contacts.  However the Contact Key is hosted on a different server, which holds the preference channel, and it's virtually impossible to retrieve the value.

So I was thinking of using the Delay Registration Until the Contact Key is set function so as not to register the contact and device to MobilePush.

I will then import the contact via import activity to the Mobile Push Contacts.

My questions are:

- How does the Delay Registration function works?  Let's say the user
  installed and login to the app.  When using the Delay Registration and
  without setting the Contact Key, will the user record be added as a
  contact in Mobile Push?
- If the contact is not added, then what happen to the user?
- Is it feasible, importing the contacts using this method?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet does exactly what it says: the device will not register with the Marketing Cloud until a `ContactKey` is set within your application via the SDK.

Comment: Thank you for the response @bill-mote. If that is the case, can we import the contact key using file import at a later stage so as to avoid the registration of the device during login?

Comment: You control when the device is registered by setting the `ContactKey`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @bill-mote!  Much appreciated